# Laravel 4 - SQL query to Laravel Eloquent query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on a school project and I'm trying to get a query working.

```
SELECT *
FROM `ziekmeldingen` AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM `ziekmeldingen` AS b
     WHERE `ziek` = 1
       AND a.personell_id = b.personell_id)
```

Name of the model: ZiekmeldingenModel

I tried 2 things, both dont work ->

```
$medewerkers = ZiekmeldingenModel::whereNotExists(function($query)
        {
            $query->select()->from('ziekmeldingen AS b')->where('ziek', '=', '1')->where('ziekmeldingen.personell_id', '=', 'b.personell_id');
        })->get();
    return $medewerkers;
```

And

```
$medewerkers = ZiekmeldingenModel::raw('SELECT * FROM `ziekmeldingen` as a WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `ziekmeldingen` as b WHERE `ziek` = 1 AND a.personell_id = b.personell_id)')->get();
```

Both of them give back all the results from the table while it should only give back 1 result (I've tested the original query, it works).

EDIT: Forgot to mention I'm using relationships in the model. So the raw solution probably won't work anyway

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Had to use a combo of both the things I tried.

```
$medewerkers = ZiekmeldingenModel::select()
                    ->from(DB::raw('`ziekmeldingen` AS a'))
                    ->whereNotExists(function($query){
                          $query->select()
                          ->from(DB::raw('`ziekmeldingen` AS b'))
                          ->whereRaw('`ziek` = 1 AND a.personell_id = b.personell_id');
                    })->get();

return $medewerkers;
```

Thanks for any help and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely no need for `select()`. Also no raw in `from` or `whereRaw` needed.

The only unusual thing here is raw piece in the where, since you don't want `table.field` to be bound and treated as string. Also, you can use `whereRaw` for the whole clause in case you have your tables prefixed, otherwise you would end up with something like `DB_PREFIX_a.personell_id`, so obviously wrong.

This is how you do it:

```
$medewerkers = ZiekmeldingenModel::from('ziekmeldingen AS a')
  ->whereNotExists(function ($q) {
     $q->from('ziekmeldingen AS b')
       ->where('ziek', 1)
       ->where('a.personell_id', DB::raw('b.personell_id'))
       // or:
       // ->whereRaw('a.personell_id = b.personell_id');
  })->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the take() method though if you're not ordering your results the record you get back could be any of the results.

```
$medewerkers = ZiekmeldingenModel::raw('SELECT * FROM `ziekmeldingen` as a WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `ziekmeldingen` as b WHERE `ziek` = 1 AND a.personell_id = b.personell_id)')->take(1)->get();
```